# Games freezing on Steam

Tags: drivers, wine, games, steam

I've heard of AMD drivers. I don't know if that's something that already comes with Linux(Ubuntu) I've tried, and I think that I was probably doing it wrong because of it's not working.

Every time I try to play a game on Steam it freezes on loading window.
I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried downloading/Installing Wine, but I have no idea how to use it.

I think it's a graphics problem. What to do?.

---

Machine Specifications

> Processor Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q9400 @2.66GHz x 4
>
> Graphics  Intel
>   Q45/Q43
>
> OS        Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit

Comment: Seriously, you should at least know your system's version. There's no 14.02, probably 14.04 LTS. The Linux kernel does come with graphic drivers, but mostly community-driven ones. Search for "Additional Drivers" in the dash to install the proprietary ones. If you installed Wine you can run .exe binaries simply by right-clicking them and clicking "open with Wine", or "open with" then "Wine" to make it permanent. Yeah, you sure do need more information (lots of it).

Comment: Eduardo thanks can you tell me other common sense stuff I should know

Comment: Yes, sure. First, know that Linux is a kernel, not an Operating System. So when you go to a forum to ask something, always specify your Operating System (in your case, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, you didn't tell us if it's 32 or 64 bits). Also try including more details about your hardware, such as CPU architecture, GPU model, RAM memory, CPU clock velocity, etc. Also don't be afraid of the command line. Even though it's not required, it's the fastest way of doing anything. When you get used to it you start loving the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Boba,

As Eduardo said you can go to additional drivers to install the Proprietary driver. Hit the super key (Windows Key) and type, "Additional Drivers". You should be able to click on the Additional drivers icon.

[Additional Drivers in the Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm2xO.jpg)

After that, the application will scan for additional drivers, and present you with a list. I generally go for the one labeled (Proprietary, tested)
Click on the one you want and then click the "Apply Changes" Button. Then you'll want to Reboot.

[Additional Driver select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx5Xl.jpg)

Also, it will help others help you if you know some basic information about your system. You can find out what version of Ubuntu are running by hitting the super key and typing, "Details".